# Redefine a global variable through DOM (forEach addEventListener)

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, global-variables

I'm trying to create a rock-paper-scissors game, but I seem to be stuck with global/local declaration of one of my variables. I found a similar problem with people using functions, but I can't seem to translate the solutions to using DOM methods.

```
let playerChoice;

const playerBtns = document.querySelectorAll("button");
playerBtns.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        let playerChoice = button.id;
    });
});
```

The issue I'm running into is that playerChoice is declared locally and one of my other functions is trying to pick up this variable globally.

Is there any way I can redefine playerChoice globally?

For the function roundWinner() below, playerChoice is undefined.

```
function compSelection() {
    choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];

    let compChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
    return choices[compChoice];
} 

function roundWinner() {
    const outcome = {
        rock: {lose: "paper", win: "scissors"},
        paper: {lose: "scissors", win: "rock"},
        scissors: {lose: "rock", win: "paper"}
    }

    if (outcome[playerChoice].win === compChoice()) {
        alert("You win!");
    } else if (outcome[playerChoice].lose === compChoice()) {
        alert("Computer wins!");
    } else {
        alert("Tie!");
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Simplest way, rename either variable. However Its always a bad idea to maintain a global variable. It adds a sideeffect

Comment: Just use `roundWinner` as event handler instead of only changing the content of a global variable.

Comment: `=== compChoice()` should be `=== compSelection()`, and you only want to call it once and not on every `if ( ... )`.